# MS access calculated field sub table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, calculated-field

I would like to add a calculated field to many of my tables and will be able to use this new technique many times.

I have sub records such as values for SalePrice and I would like to have these totals show in an employees record.

I would appreciate a sample query and how to implement considering the following data:

- Table 1 (Employees): ID, EmployeeName, [Calculated Field]
- Table 2 (Sales):     ID, InventoryItem, SalePrice, QuantityOrdered

I would like to fetch [SalePrice] x [QuantityOrdered] in 2 scenarios:

- Total Sales to date
- Total Sales within a date range (where these 2 values can be entered
  on a form) for administration purposes as our employees are paid
  commission only.

I'm used to adding table fields in both Layout and Design view.

Kind regards, Mikey.

Comment: Maybe not the best idea to persist the values in the base tables and keep them in queries.  It's not like SQL Server where those values will update regularly and reliably.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Could you please help me to work out how I could get these values with a query and then put the value into a field?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started: MS Access SQL: http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/access-help/access-sql-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-HA010256402.aspx.  Calculated fields in queries: http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/access-help/create-a-calculated-field-in-a-query-mdb-HP005188023.aspx.

Comment: You will need to add an EmployeeId field in the Sales table so you can track sales by employee.

Comment: Oops, sorry, meant this as a comment, not an answer.  Still applies, though.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was meant for Mikey.

Comment: Thanks for your input friends.  I will look into your suggestions. :-)